# Operating system agnostic way to get config file in clojure

Tags: file-io, clojure

I have a few clojure applications that load the sensitive info off of `.properties` file in `/etc/` and this has worked well so far.

Recently, I have had to deal with a few windows machines added into our server collection and I need to run the clojure applications on there as well. Windows doesn't obviously have or understand `/etc/` path and I got around that fact by looking at `/etc/` and if that's missing then looking at `d:\configs`.

But I don't quite like this way of doing it, because, if there is another windows developer looking into it and he doesn't have `d:\` or prefers elsewhere for configs it would get messy.

Is there any way I can load a file from clojure, no matter what operating system it is? My initial thoughts were of saving a key-path in the Environment variable and accessing it from clojure.

I am just wondering if there is a better way of doing it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Storing config in a project directory may help, because relative path should work on any OS.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny - My project manager is strictly against that, people might commit it to github and whatnot.. that's not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: Your solution, EnvVar is what I would use.

Comment: So, doesn't your manager trust `.gitignore`?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny he does, but he doesn't trust the intern who would start a new project and commit. Lets not make this question about that, I cannot use relative paths to store the configs and I'd like a way to get the path of config regardless of the underlying OS. If you have any ideas on that front, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: I concur with @Chiron, environment vars seem your safest bet. Plus, there are some that are available on most operating systems (e.g. `HOME`), meaning that you probably wouldn't have to configure your environment at all if you use a path like `$HOME/.my-important-stuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [environ](https://github.com/weavejester/environ). It offers some flexibility when it comes to configuring your Clojure app, letting you choose between a number of options:

- **environment variables**: This seems to be the way to go in Clojureland, so I'd say your initial thought wasn't the worst;
- **in `~/.lein/profiles.clj`**: You can store them in the `:user` profile as Clojure data - that sounds quite nice, I guess;
- **Java CLI properties**: Finally, you can pass them to the `java` executable directly via the command line.

`environ` will collect data from all these places.

Comment: Thanks, Looking into the library, I think I'll go with environment variables after all!